# Project only matching array items grouped from different documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say we have 2 different type of documents. First kind stores `addresses` and second one stores `cars and boats for each person identified by its national document (dni)`.

Consider following 4 documents:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "i" : ObjectId("575e6522d51ef71dbe128bd0"),
        "dni" : "72999995X"
    },
    "data" : {
        "addresses" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "avenue",
                "name" : "gran via",
                "number" : 112
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "street",
                "name" : "mayor",
                "number" : 23
            }
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "i" : ObjectId("575e657dd51ef71dbe128bd1"),
        "dni" : "72999994B"
    },
    "data" : {
        "addresses" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "avenue",
                "name" : "gran via",
                "number" : 112
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "road",
                "name" : "N-112",
                "km" : 430
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "road",
                "name" : "N-112",
                "km" : 440
            }
        ]
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "i" : ObjectId("575e65cdd51ef71dbe128bd2"),
        "dni" : "72999995X"
    },
    "data" : {
        "cars" : [ 
            {
                "fuel" : "gas",
                "color" : "black",
                "brand" : "BMW"
            }, 
            {
                "fuel" : "gas",
                "color" : "white",
                "brand" : "Mercedes"
            }
        ],
        "boats" : [ 
            {
                "year" : 1998,
                "engines" : 1,
                "tank" : 2250
            }, 
            {
                "year" : 2015,
                "engines" : 2,
                "tank" : 4100
            }
        ]
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "i" : ObjectId("575e664ad51ef71dbe128bd3"),
        "dni" : "72999994B"
    },
    "data" : {
        "cars" : [ 
            {
                "fuel" : "diesel",
                "color" : "gray",
                "brand" : "BMW"
            }, 
            {
                "fuel" : "gas",
                "color" : "blue",
                "brand" : "Opel"
            }, 
            {
                "fuel" : "gas",
                "color" : "black",
                "brand" : "BMW"
            }
        ],
        "boats" : [ 
            {
                "year" : 2001,
                "engines" : 2,
                "tank" : 2550
            }, 
            {
                "year" : 2014,
                "engines" : 3,
                "tank" : 4000
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Question is then... How can I get only those items from each array matching a condition which applies to 2+ different documents?

For instance... Who lives in `mayor` and owns `gas` cars and project matching values.

This is my approach:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {'$group': {'_id': {'dni': '$_id.dni'}, 'data': {'$addToSet':'$data'}}},
    {'$match': {'$and': [{'data.cars.fuel':'gas'}, {'data.addresses.name':'mayor'}]}},
    {'$unwind': '$data'},
    {'$unwind': {'path': '$data.cars', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true}},
    {'$unwind': {'path': '$data.addresses', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true}},
    {'$match': {'$or': [{'data.cars.fuel':'gas'}, {'data.addresses.name':'mayor'}]}},
    {'$project': {'data.cars': 1, 'data.addresses': 1}}
])
```

This pipeline actually returns what I want:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "dni" : "72999995X"
    },
    "data" : {
        "cars" : {
            "fuel" : "gas",
            "color" : "black",
            "brand" : "BMW"
        }
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "dni" : "72999995X"
    },
    "data" : {
        "cars" : {
            "fuel" : "gas",
            "color" : "white",
            "brand" : "Mercedes"
        }
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "dni" : "72999995X"
    },
    "data" : {
        "addresses" : {
            "type" : "street",
            "name" : "mayor",
            "number" : 23
        }
    }
}
```

However I have had to change `$and by $or in $match stage` since after `$unwind` stage every value has gone to different documents.

This would be fine if would be a GENERIC solution but it's not. What if now I want to get persons who owns simultaneously `'gas' cars` and `boats with 2+ engines`?

`$match` stages would look like this:

```
{'$match': {'$and': [{'data.cars.fuel':'gas'}, {'data.boats.engines':{'$gt':1}}]}},
```

but both times should be `$and` because after `$unwind`, both cars and boats belongs to the same document.

(e.g:)

```
/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "dni" : "72999994B"
    },
    "data" : {
        "cars" : {
            "fuel" : "gas",
            "color" : "black",
            "brand" : "BMW"
        },
        "boats" : {
            "year" : 2014,
            "engines" : 3,
            "tank" : 4000
        }
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to `$unwind` them to different documents?

Otherwise... how can I reach a generic pipeline to achieve every kind of query without altering my schema?